# "It would be nice if it rains", grammatically correct?

Tags: conditional-constructions

As you read in the headline, if I say "if it rains, it would be nice", is it correct? It is like a mixture of first and second conditional, but I don't know whether it exists or not.

Comment: Yes it was a typing mistake

Comment: I edited your question but it shows no research and the title sentence has the phrases switched in contrast to the question body. If you don't add basic research and explain why think the sentence might be incorrect this is general proofreading and thus off-topic. Have a look at the [help] for more information.

Comment: 'It would be nice if it rained', or 'It will be nice if it rains."

Comment: @KateBunting Absolutely correct, but you don't hear that from a British person very often!

Answer (score -1):

Your questions seem to be if either / both are grammatically correct:

> 1. "It would be nice if it rains."
> 2. "If it rains, it would be nice."

Both are acceptable.

You can also indicate raining as a complete action:

> "It would be nice if it rained."

More formally, you can also emphasize that the rain is in doubt:

> "It would be nice if it were to rain."

Comment: How can you think that? Weren’t Kate and BoldBen indeed "absolutely correct”?

Are you saying it’s OK to mix the conditionals? Don’t you think “It would be nice if it rains…” and “If it rains, it would be nice” ‘acceptable’ only in as much as they can be understood?

Even if it is, d’you think most people will hear a complete action in "It would be nice if it rained" 
without being offered something like ”… if it started to rain" for comparison… unless the idea is that even divine intervention is not going to start a rain that never stops?